# @Version or Trigger?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, triggers

I want to add a column 'LastModification' in all tables, this column will store the modification date of the relevant rows, frameworks used in my web application are : SpringMVC, Hibernate and MySQL database.

my questions are :

- The new column will be the type: datetime or timestamp? according to
  my research, I have not found datetime has greater range, but is
  there any risk or limit that I could have for the future?
- side performance, is it better to add trigger for each table that
  will update the column 'LastModification,' or I have to necessarily
  use the annotation 'Version? I tried to implementVersion but I had a
  lot of error, the solution requires a change in existing annotations
  entitées (ie: cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,etc ...), and I ' have no
  right to change it :( so I plan to add triggers but I do not know is it
  will impact the performance of my database or not ?

The script below is an example of the trigger that I intend to implement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_i_table001
BEFORE INSERT ON table001
FOR EACH ROW  SET NEW.lastModification = Now();

CREATE TRIGGER trg_u_table001
BEFORE UPDATE ON table001
FOR EACH ROW   SET NEW.LastModification = Now();
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you hoping to provide optimistic locking or simply recording when a record was modified?

Don't use `@Version` timestamps with MySQL as it will throw exceptions if you update the same record too fast (low resolution on timestamp values). Always use `int` with `@Version`.

If you have only one application writing to the database, you can keep the logic in the application. If multiple applications, use the db (triggers).

You'll probably save a lot of time if you can use Spring Data JPA auditing feature:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#auditing

This lets you add a `@LastModifiedDate` annotation to a field which SDJ will automatically update for you. Lets you track who the user was too if they are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with Spring Data JPA, Spring has made it as easy using annotation `@CreatedBy, @CreatedDate, @LastModifiedBy, @LastModifiedDate` on your fields. You can follow below simple example

```
// Will need to enable JPA Auditing
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorAware")
class JpaConfig {
    // Creating a bean of AuditorAwareImpl which will provide currently logged in user
    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorAware() {
        return new AuditorAwareImpl();
    }
}

// Moving necessary fields to super class and providing AuditingEntityListener entity listner class
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
abstract class Auditable<U> {

    @CreatedBy
    protected U createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date createdDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    protected U lastModifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date lastModifiedDate;

    // Getters and Setters
}

// Creating implementation of AuditorAware and override its methods to provide currently logged in user
class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public String getCurrentAuditor() {
        return "Naresh";
        // Can use Spring Security to return currently logged in user
        // return ((User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUsername()
    }
}

@Entity
class File extends Auditable<String> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String content;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

You can read [Spring Data JPA Auditing: Saving CreatedBy, CreatedDate, LastModifiedBy, LastModifiedDate automatically](https://programmingmitra.blogspot.in/2017/02/automatic-spring-data-jpa-auditing-saving-CreatedBy-createddate-lastmodifiedby-lastmodifieddate-automatically.html)  for more details